# Permissão de acesso para um sistema PHP + AD + Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, autenticação, ad, permissões

Bom dia,

Sou novo no PHP e estou começando um sistema para a empresa que eu trabalho, gerando relatórios.

Atualmente meu código PHP se autentica com um Active Directory normalmente, e ao conectar, ele vai para uma página com varios relatórios.

Esses relatórios fazem uma conexão temporária com um Banco de Dados Oracle 10g e ao terminar a exibição do código, fechar essa conexão.

Porém, o meu problema, é que todos os usuários tem acesso a todos os relatórios, o que fica inviável, pois tem relatórios que apenas a Diretoria pode acessar, enquanto alguns relatórios apenas o setor Fiscal, e assim por diante.

Eu procurei algumas soluções, mas não achei nada que eu conseguisse aplicar no meu ambiente.

Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue dar uma luz para meu problema:

Quero que as permissões de cada relatórios fiquem por usuário ou grupo, de preferencia que eu consiga dar as permissões direto no AD.

É possível?

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você esta autenticando uma base LDAP, obviamente consegue fazer consulta a qual grupo esses usuários pertecem. Em PHP existe uma função onde você traz esses grupos, parte da ideia onde o grupo "Diretoria" pode ver tais relatórios e o grupo "operadoradores" podem ver apenas estes outros relátorios. Na prática em PHP, ao fazer a consulta de qual grupo o usuario pertecem, pode fazer condições usando o Switch ou até um IF mesmo. Exemplos:

```
Switch "$usuario->grupo"{
Case "Diretoria":
echo "Olá, estes são os relatórios diretoria"
break;
Case "Operador":
echo "Olá, estes são os relatórios operador"
break;
default:
echo "Olá, voce não faz parte de nenhum grupo, contate o administrador"
break;
}
```

**Utilizando IF**

```
if($usuario->grupo == "Diretoria"){
    echo "Olá, estes são os relatórios diretoria"
}
elseif($usuario->grupo == "Operador"){
echo "Olá, estes são os relatórios operador"
}
```

Bom, eu só citei alguns exemplos, claro que vai da sua lógica de programação. Espero ter ajudado.

Obs: Para consultas em LDAP usando PHP, como trazer o grupo, de uma lida em http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.ldap.php

Abs.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Seguindo suas dicas eu consegui o que precisava.